# Bind NSSegmentedControl to a boolean?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, cocoa-bindings

I'm still new to Cocoa Bindings and I haven't found an answer to this question even after looking through the docs.  What I want to do is have a segmented control that only has two segments.  If the first segment is selected, then a preference in NSUserDefaults should be YES , but if the second segment is selected, then the preference should be NO.  This is trivial to do through code:

```
-(IBAction)segmentSelectionChanged:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selectedSegment = [sender selectedSegment];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:(selectedSegment==0)?YES:NO forKey:@"somepref"];
}
```

but I'd like to do it through bindings (selected index looks promising).  Any way to do something like this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got it already -- binding the control's `selectedIndex` in IB:

```
Bind To: Shared User Defaults Controller
Controller Key: values
Key Path: WhateverYouWant
```

seems to work just fine.

Is the problem that you *really* need it to be a `BOOL`? It's just a `typedef` for `signed char` anyways. See objc.h, lines 43, 49, and 50:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL;
// ...
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

You can pull the value back out using `integerForKey:` and cast it (possibly better because more explicit):

```
(BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"WhateverYouWant"];
```

or just continue using `boolForKey:` and it should work fine.

Comment: Well, I'm accessing the preference via `boolForKey`.  Does that method automatically convert "1" into YES and vice versa?

Comment: They're exactly equivalent. If you look at objc.h, lines 43, 49, and 50 are: `typedef signed char  BOOL;`, `#define YES             (BOOL)1` and `#define NO              (BOOL)0`. Anywhere you have a `BOOL`, you can treat it as an integer.

Comment: Thanks.  I also have another question regarding bindings, not sure if you can help.  When this value changes, I want another (bound) value to change also.  How would I set up those values to listen for a change in this preference?  They are also set up through IB.

Comment: You can bind it also. `[myObject bind:myValue toObject:[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] withKeyPath:@"values.sameKeyThatIUsedForTheSegmentedControl" options:nil]`.

Comment: No, not now that I've got my check mark...kidding. The control doesn't come up with the same segment selected from launch to launch? Did you delete your comment? Is it working?

Comment: @Josh: I also found `NSNegateBoolean`, which did what I needed it to do...both by negating the boolean and actually by saving the preference as a boolean instead of an integer.  And yes, sorry for the quick deletion of the comment as I found that I had a method that was setting the segment before it even had a chance to save the preference. :)

Comment: Glad it's sorted out! Isn't `NSNegateBoolean` backwards, though?

Comment: That's what I needed it to be. ;)

Comment: @Josh: Also, regarding the manual binding I'm just not sure that's what I want to do.  I mean, I have like 20 textfields that basically have the same data sent to them.  They're bound to NSStrings in a certain class.  So, when this segment is toggled I want those strings to "refresh", because I have them all set to a value transformer that checks that preference and if it is YES, then it converts a value into something else.  So, if those values would only think they were changed so it could pass it through the value transformer then it would do what I'm hoping.  Makes sense right? :P

Comment: I'm not sure I followed that. :/ Have a look at [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), specifically [willChangeValueForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-BBCCIJAJ)?